# What's the differences between a numpy matrix and a numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, types

I read in a csv file and did some manipulations, and got an object x. When I use `type(x)`, it returns `numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix`. I have never seen this type before and wondering if there is any difference between it and a commonly seen 'numpy matrix'. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.matrix
Out[2]: numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix

In [3]: id(np.matrix)
Out[3]: 4300190472

In [4]: id(np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix)
Out[4]: 4300190472

In [5]: a = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [6]: type(a)
Out[6]: numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix
```

`numpy.matrix` is a more convenient name for `numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix`.